# Javascript: see POST and GET info

Tags: javascript, get

Today I had a situation, when I want to send some info from my Tornado backend to frontend with backbone. And I have the question - can I receive GET or POST info with my client-side javascript and why?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing the server? using AJAX i presume. You can examine the response headers in javascript:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

// do your GET request

//in the callback 
request.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
```